# Solving a system of linear inequalities in Matlab and getting the entire set of solutions

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, inequalities

I want to solve a system of linear inequalities in Matlab, where the unknowns are `x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)`. I want the **entire** set of solutions `x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4)`. Hence, I can't use `linprog` because it gives me just one feasible point.

**Clarification:** This question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37258835/how-to-set-the-objective-function-when-using-linprog-in-matlab-to-solve-a-system was about `linprogr` which however gives only one possible solution. Here I'm asking how to find the entire set of solutions.

This is the set of inequalities. Any suggestion?

```
5x(1)+3x(2)+3x(3)+5x(4)<5
-5x(1)-3x(2)-3x(3)-5x(4)<-3
-x(2)-x(3)<0
x(2)+x(3)<1
-x(1)-x(4)<0
x(1)+x(4)<1
-3x(3)-5x(4)<-1
3x(3)+5x(4)>3
x(3)<1
-x(3)<0
x(4)<1
-x(4)<0
-5x(1)-3x(2)<0
5x(1)+3x(2)<2
x(2)<1
-x(2)<0
x(1)<1
-x(1)<0
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The other question was about linprogr. Here I explicitly state that I do not want to use linprogr.

Comment: I agree with the poster: it is not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With continuous variables we basically have zero, one or infinitely many solutions. Of course showing all the solutions is not possible for this. However, there is a concept of corner points in linear programming, and those points we can enumerate, although with much effort.

Here are some links for tools that can do this:

- [cdd](https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/fukudak/cdd_home/)
- [ppl](http://bugseng.com/products/ppl)

A different approach is to enumerate the optimal bases using extra binary variables. (You have a zero objective so this becomes effectively: enumerating all feasible LP bases). This approach makes the problem a MIP. We can enumerate this by an algorithm like:

1. solve mip
2. if infeasible: stop
3. add constraint to forbid current point
4. goto step 1

Here is a [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/01/finding-all-optimal-lp-solutions.html) that illustrates this approach to enumerate all optimal bases of a (continuous) LP problem.

Note that enumerating all integer solutions of a system of inequalities is easier. Many constraint programming tools will do that for you automatically. In addition we can use the "cutting plane" technique described above.

Comment: Well said, Yes if you are looking for a SET of solutions the variables must be integers otherwise there is no way to define the set of solutions (except the inequalities mentioned themselves)